# My If/else statement is not executing properly

Tags: c#

So I made a basic game for a school assignment. One of the requirements is, to let program choose who is playing first, either the computer or the player. So I wrote an if/else statement then put my code inside of it. The code works, but then I added code which limits what numbers the player can input. Those numbers range from 1-3. If a players inputs a number less than one or greater than three they get an error message. After my if/else executed which picks the player who goes first, it stops working and only picks the player and not the computer. Is there a way to fix this?

```
int chips = 21, user, computer;
int pickPlayer;
Random rn = new Random();
pickPlayer = rn.Next(1, 5);
if (pickPlayer == 1 || pickPlayer == 2 || pickPlayer == 3 )
{
    //Player goes First
    while (chips > 0)    
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} Chips Choose Either 1,2,3 chips", chips);
        user = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (user > 3 || user <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You can only take between 1 and 3 chips. Try again");                            
        }
        else
        {
            chips = chips - user;
            Random rnd = new Random();

            /*if (chips <= 0)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Lose");
                Console.ReadLine();
            } */

        }
        if (chips <= 0)    
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You Lose");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }    
    }
}
else
{
    //Computer goes first
    while (chips > 0)    
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} Chips Choose Either 1,2,3 or 4 chips", chips);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        computer = rnd.Next(1, 4);
        user = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Computer picks {0} chips", computer);

        chips = chips - computer;

        if (chips <= 0)    
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You Lose");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }    
        else    
        {
            if (user > 3 || user <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You can only take between 1 and 3 chips. Try again");
            }
            else
            {
                chips = chips - user;
                /*if (chips <= 0)

                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("You Win");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                } */
            }
            if (chips <= 0)    
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("You Win");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what a *method* is?  Your program is hard to read and understand and debug because you're not using methods.

Comment: your `while` should surround the `if`statements, when upon each turn you wish to choose who starts, now it will pick, go into the `if` or `else` branch and then be in the `while` loop until there are no more `chips`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

I corrected the algorithm and I refactored the code using anonymous methods and changing names but you can create class methods instead.

I used int.TryParse instead of Convert so it returns only a number or 0 in case of error.

```
Random random = new Random();
int chipsStart = 21;
int chipsCurrent = chipsStart;
int playerTake;
int computerTake;
bool playerFirst = random.Next(0, 2) == 0;

Func<bool> processPlayer = () =>
{
  Console.WriteLine("There are {0} Chips Choose Either 1,2,3 chips", chipsCurrent);
  do
  {
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out playerTake);
  }
  while ( playerTake == 0 );
  if ( playerTake < 1 || playerTake > 3 )
    Console.WriteLine("You can only take between 1 and 3 chips. Try again");
  else
    chipsCurrent = chipsCurrent - playerTake;
  if ( chipsCurrent > 0 )
    return true;
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("You Lose");
    return false;
  }
};

Func<bool> processComputer = () =>
{
  computerTake = random.Next(1, 4);
  Console.WriteLine("Computer picks {0} chips", computerTake);
  chipsCurrent = chipsCurrent - computerTake;
  if ( chipsCurrent > 0 )
    return true;
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("You Win");
    return false;
  }
};

if ( playerFirst )
  while ( true )
  {
    if ( !processPlayer() ) break;
    if ( !processComputer() ) break;
  }
else
  while ( true )
  {
    if ( !processPlayer() ) break;
    if ( !processComputer() ) break;
  }

Console.ReadLine();
```